# Populate model of the model with sails js

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to populate model of the model with sails unfortunally it doesn't work.

I have 3 models

```
/**
  Conversation.js

**/
module.exports = {

    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    tableName:'conversation',
    attributes: {
        idConversation:{
            columnName:'IDCONVERSATION',
            primaryKey:true,
            autoIncrement:true,
            unique:true,
            type:'integer',
            index:true
        },
        dateStartConversation:{
          columnName:'DATEDEBUT',
          type:'date',
          index:true
        },
        user1:{
            columnName:'IDUSER1',
            model:'user',
            notNull:true
        },
        user2:{
            columnName:'IDUSER2',
            model:'user',
            notNull:true
        },
        article:
        {
          model:'article',
          columnName:'IDARTICLE',
          notNull:true
        }
    }
};



/**
   Article.js
**/
module.exports = {
    autoPK: false,
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    tableName:'article',
    attributes: {
        idArticle:{
            type:'integer',
            unique:true,
            columnName:'IDARTICLE',
            autoIncrement:true,
            primaryKey:true
        },
        title:{
            type:'string',
            required:true,
            columnName:'TITRE',
            index:true,
            notNull:true
        },
        utilisateur:{
            model:'utilisateur',
            columnName:'IDUTILISATEUR',
            required:true,
            notNull:true,
            dominant:true
        },
        images:{
            collection:'image',
            via:'article'
        },

        conversation:{
          collection:'conversation',
          via:'article'
        }
    }
};

/**
   Image.js
**/
module.exports = {
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    tableName:'image',
    attributes: {
        idImage:{
            columnName:'IDIMAGE',
            primaryKey:true,
            autoIncrement:true,
            unique:true,
            type:'integer'
        },
        pathImage:{
            columnName:'PATHIMAGE',
            required:true,
            type:'string',
            notNull:true
        },
        article:{
            model:'article',
            columnName:'IDARTICLE',
            notNull:true,
            dominant:true

        }
    }
};
```

As you can see in my model, an conversation its between Two user, about one article, and those article cas have one or many Images.

So I want to get all conversations of one user and I able to populate with article but I'm not able to populate article with Image below how I proceed

```
 Conversation.find().populate('article').populate('user1').populate('user2').where({
      or : [
        { user1: iduser },
        { user2: iduser }
      ]})
    .then(function( conversations) {
        var i=0;
        conversations.forEach(function(element,index){
          i++;
          console.log("article "+index+" "+JSON.stringify(element.article));
          Article.findOne({
            idArticle:element.article.idArticle
          }).populate('images').then(function(newArticle){
            //I  try to set article with the newArticle but it don't work
            element.article=newArticle;
          })
          if(i==conversations.length){

            res.json({
              hasConversation:true,
              conversation:conversations
            });
          }
        });

    })
```

Because deep populate is not possible using sails, I try to use a loop to populate each article with associate Images and set it in conversation, But article is never set in conversation.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the `if(i==conversations.length)` at the end, you seem to have an inkling that you need to write asynchronous code.  But you're iterating `i` inside of the synchronous `forEach` loop, so your response is happening before any of the database queries even run.  Move the `i++` and the `if` inside of the callback for `Article.findOne`:

```
 Conversation.find().populate('article').populate('user1').populate('user2').where({
      or : [
        { user1: iduser },
        { user2: iduser }
      ]})
    .then(function( conversations) {
        var i=0;
        conversations.forEach(function(element,index){
          console.log("article "+index+" "+JSON.stringify(element.article));
          Article.findOne({
            idArticle:element.article.idArticle
          }).populate('images').then(function(newArticle){
            // Associate the article with the conversation,
            // calling `toObject` on it first
            element.article= newArticle.toObject();
            // Done processing this conversation
            i++;
            // If we're done processing ALL of the conversations, send the response
            if(i==conversations.length){
              res.json({
                hasConversation:true,
                conversation:conversations
              });
            }

          })
        });

    })
```

You'll also need to call `toObject` on the `newArticle` instance before assigning it to the conversation, because it contains getters and setters on the `images` property which behave unexpectedly when copied.

I'd also recommend refactoring this to use [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), which will make it more readable.

Comment: Hello sgress454, i had already tried what you propose but result is still the same,  current article in conversation is not update with newArticle

Comment: Also, can you update your anwser with refactoring code using async.each ?

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to add the `toObject` call on the `newArticle` instance.  Updated the code with some explanation.  As far as `async.each`, as you said--it's a refactor.  I was just suggesting that it could make the code more readable, but it's not necessary to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Until this is resolved (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/108), you can use this function that I developed to solve this: https://gist.github.com/dinana/52453ecb00d469bb7f12